# No entiendo porque al crear una variable de tipo String me da error : type mismatch : cannot convert from java.lang.String to string

Tags: string

Me aparece ="Helena" subrayado en rojo y no entiendo porque...

```
public class String {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String nombre = "Helena";
        
        System.out.println("Bienvenida "+nombre);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

EL problema que tienes es que has llamado a tu clase `String`, recuerda que hay palabras reservadas para el lenguaje y que si haces uso de ellas lo más normal es que te produzca errores.

Al nombrar variables, clases, interfaces y demás cosas intenta no usar palabras como por ejemplo:

- `int`
- `String`
- `Class`
- `public`
- `final`
- Y un largo etc..

Para ver cuales son te dejo un link:

- [Palabras reservadas en java](https://www.ciberaula.com/cursos/java/palabras_reservadas_java.php)

Para solucionar tu problema basta con que cambies el nombre de la clase.

```java
// Tu fichero se llamaría String.java y tu clase String (NO debes usar palabras reservadas)
public class String { // String es una palabra reservada
    public static void main(java.lang.String[] args) {
        String nombre = "Helena";
        System.out.println("Bienvenida  "+nombre);
    }
}
```

Con el siguiente cambio ya debería funcionar.

```java
// EL fichero se llama MiString.java y la clase MiString (No son palabras reservadas)
public class MiString {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[] args) {
        String nombre = "Helena";
        System.out.println("Bienvenida  "+nombre);
    }
}
```

Comment: Es verdad!!muchas gracias Rafael!!